# filter content of resource_jars in java_library in bazel

Tags: java, scala, build, bazel

In **bazel** I see that `java_library` rule allows me to configure [`resource_jars` attribute](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_library.resource_jars) - which is great.

I want to filter the content I'm copying from those archives such that only files with certain pattern will be copied in? (i.e -  only `*.txt` resources or `*.xml` resources) Is there a built in way to do that?

Comment: Hi Orshachar, I have similar required, let me know if you can share exmple like how can i call gen rule . I need to filter file in registry/*.json and create a new jar/tar file.

Answer (score 2):

Not really built-in, but you can do it yourself with something like:

```
genrule(
    name = "jar-filter",
    srcs = [":input.jar"],
    outputs = ["output.jar"],
    cmd = """
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
cd $tmpdir
jar xf $(location :input.jar)
for $$i in $$(find *); do
    # Remove any files that don't end with the right extensions.
    if expr match "$$i" '.*\(.txt\)' || expr match "$$i" '.*\(.xml\)'; then
      continue
    else
      rm $$i
    fi
done
jar cf $@ *  # Creates the new jar file.
""",
)
```

Then you can depend on `output.jar` from other targets.

Comment: thanks @kristina ! That should work indeed. I am writing a Skylark packaging rule and I thought of doing that but I was afraid traversing the entire tree would hurt the performance. I thought there is a more efficient way to do it using some skylark graph.

Comment: can i mention multiple srcs files like  srcs = [
        ":abc-search",
        "//mp/search:xyzsearch"
    ] ?

Comment: @PrakashPanjwani yes, then refer to them as `$(location :abc-search)` and `$(location //mp/search:xyzsearch)` in the command.

Comment: @kristina : thanks for reply , Can i loop for dependency mentioned in src ?  like if i have 10 and i want to do same process for each jar.

Comment: Check out the [genrule documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule) and examples. You can use `$(SRCS)` and/or `$(locations //whatever)` for multiple files, depending on situation.